# Implement the subcommand pattern in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Is it possible to implement the subcommand pattern in PowerShell?  Something like:

```
command [subcommand] [options] [files]
```

Examples: Git, svn, Homebrew

What would be the general architecture?  A single function that delegates the actual work to script blocks?  Each subcommand isolated in its own `PS1` file that is dot-sources by the primary script?  Would PowerShell's various meta-data functions (e.g. `Get-Command`) be able to 'inspect' the subcommands?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I thought of this pattern and found two ways of doing this. I did not find
real applications in my practice, so the research is rather academic. But
the scripts below work fine.

An existing tool which implements this pattern (in its own way) is
[scoop](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop).

---

The pattern *subcommand* implements the classic command line interface

```
app <command> [parameters]
```

This pattern introduces a single script `app.ps1` which provides commands
instead of providing multiple scripts or functions in a script library or
module. Each command is a script in the special subdirectory, e.g. *./Command*.

Get available commands

```
app
```

Invoke a command

```
app c1 [parameters of Command\c1.ps1]
```

Get command help

```
app c1 -?     # works with splatting approach
app c1 -help  # works with dynamic parameters
```

The script *app.ps1* may contain common functions used by commands.

---

#### *splat.ps1* (as such *app.ps1*) - pattern with splatting

Pros:

- Minimum code and overhead.
- Positional parameters work.
- `-?` works for help as it is (short help).

Cons:

- PowerShell v3+, splatting works funny in v2.

---

#### *dynamic.ps1* (as such *app.ps1*) - pattern with dynamic parameters

Pros:

- PowerShell v2+.
- TabExpansion works for parameters.

Cons:

- More code, more runtime work.
- Only named parameters.
- Help as `-help`.

---

#### Scripts

***splat.ps1***

UPDATE: Used `$_Command` instead of `$Command` to avoid conflicts with partial parameter names like `-c`, see comments.

```
#requires -Version 3

param(
    $_Command
)

if (!$_Command) {
    foreach($_ in Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot\Command -Name) {
        [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_)
    }
    return
}

& "$PSScriptRoot\Command\$_Command.ps1" @args
```

***dynamic.ps1***

UPDATE: Added more known common parameters.

```
param(
    [Parameter()]$Command,
    [switch]$Help
)
dynamicparam {
    ${private:*pn} = 'Verbose', 'Debug', 'ErrorAction', 'WarningAction', 'ErrorVariable', 'WarningVariable', 'OutVariable', 'OutBuffer', 'PipelineVariable', 'InformationAction', 'InformationVariable', 'ProgressAction'
    $PSScriptRoot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

    $Command = $PSBoundParameters['Command']
    if (!$Command) {return}

    $_ = Get-Command -Name "$PSScriptRoot\Command\$Command.ps1" -CommandType ExternalScript -ErrorAction 1
    if (!($_ = $_.Parameters) -or !$_.Count) {return}

    ${private:*r} = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
    (${private:*a} = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Attribute]).Add((New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute))
    foreach($_ in $_.Values) {
        if (${*pn} -notcontains $_.Name) {
            ${*r}.Add($_.Name, (New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter $_.Name, $_.ParameterType, ${*a}))
        }
    }
    ${*r}
}
end {
    if (!$Command) {
        foreach($_ in Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot\Command -Name) {
            [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_)
        }
        return
    }

    if ($Help) {
        Get-Help "$PSScriptRoot\Command\$Command.ps1" -Full
        return
    }

    $null = $PSBoundParameters.Remove('Command')
    & "$PSScriptRoot\Command\$Command.ps1" @PSBoundParameters
}
```

Comment: Interesting, although I would normally stay away from using subcommands in PowerShell cmdlets (yes, yes, "advanced functions", I know, shush), particularly since comment-based help wasn't really made for this kind of interface.

Comment: I also stay away from this approach but keep it in mind for a suitable use case. Actually, a "proper use case" may depend on preferences and taste.

Comment: You should better call the only parameter in splat,ps1 $_Command. This avoids conflicts with subcommand parameters that begin with C and are specified shortened as -C, e.g.:
``.\splat.ps1 doSomething -C "Some argument"``